# Get the selected address value from Mapbox Geocoder

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I tried to get the selected address value that made by Mapbox geo-search API.(no need Map)

with .on() method, I could get the suggested addresses by insert some address into Search filed. But if I select one of them, how do I know which one has been selected?

Concerned code or API Docs path will be good help.

[image]

// HTML

```
<div id="geotest"></div>
```

// Javascript

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.asdfaesdfawefc--help-me--------------';    
geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
     }).on('results', function(results) {
        console.log(results); //check reason
});

geocoder.addTo('#geotest');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder` version `4.7.4`, and use:

```
    map.addControl(
      new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl,
      }).on('result', (selected) => {
        console.log('Selected geo: ', selected)
      })
    )
```